# Splitting a git repository with filter-branch loses ancestry

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm converting a largish git-repository into multiple repos (one per sub module) using filter-branch, but some of the commits in the sub-repos gets disconnected and does not share a parent.

The parent repository comes from a svn import (using `git svn clone`) and have a clean history with a master-trunk and releases branching of from it now and then. Ie. something like this:

```
---------------- master
 \  \  \
  \  \  \------- release-2.00
   \  \  
    \  \-------- release-1.10
     \
      \--------- release-1.00
```

I then run git filter-branch using something like:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter module1 -- --all
git push ../split-module1/ --all
```

where `../split-module1/` is a empty bare repository. <sup>1</sup>

The resulting repo will then contain a history that looks some what like this:

```
---------------- master
  \
   \------------ release-1.00

---------------- release-1.10

---------------- release-2.00
```

where it is seemingly random to me which releases are still attached to the trunk.

Is there a way of getting the branches to unite? If there is more information needed, I'm happy to supply it :-)

<sup>1</sup> This is somewhat simplified since some modules don't exist in all releases, `--all` is then substituted with the relevant releases, but I get the same result.

UPDATE: Turns out I was wrong about the global history beeing clean, some releases was hanging in the air :-( I managed to merge the history using `git pull --rebase .` and then everything worked like a charm.

Comment: I wonder if `git subtree` would be a better solution to splitting this repository?  It sounds like the `git subtree split` command would do exactly what you're trying to do with `filter-branch`.

Comment: In your resulting repo, does the contents of the root commit of a branch that turned into a trunk of its own (e.g. `release-1.10`) match any commit in the master trunk?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but here is some info:
* git subtree gives the same kind of result as filter-branch.
* It doesn't seem that the commits go into more then one branch. 
I have however found one branch in the big repo that isn't attached, which would explain that the corresponding branch in the sub repo, but not all of them. I'm trying a new import using ´subgit´ instead of ´git svn import´ to see if it attaches the loose branch.